# Spring security: do not require authentication for local request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot web application with couple of REST controllers. It uses Spring Security for form based authentication (1)

In addition the application is reading stored requests and dispatches them to itself. For this I have a custom Spring Dispatcher servlet and a filter chain for the stored request. When invoked, it lets the Spring DispatcherServlet dispatch the HTTP request to the correct REST controller (2)

I'd like to setup the Spring security in a way that it does not require authentication for the (2) case - that is when the http request comes from  the application itself.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Yep, I'd like to completely disable Spring Security for the second case. Unfortunately there's no starting path, it can be any resource.

Comment: Since I'm constructing the request then passing it back to the Spring DispatcherServlet, I think I can set an attribute - javax.servlet.ServletRequest.setAttribute. Another option would be to set a certain request header with a dynamic value (token?) and then allow request having a valid token.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but it solves the problem only technically. You need to secure this request, because you don't want to allow every body to bypass Spring Security. You can use a token (as you mentioned), but then you can also use Spring Secrity to check. Maybe a better way is to use forward instead of redirect. It will not checked again by Spring Security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom [`RequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html):

> Simple strategy to match an `HttpServletRequest`.

with your logic to decide if the request should be ignored.

Then add the custom `RequestMatcher`  with [`AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry#requestMatchers`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers-org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher...-):

> Associates a list of RequestMatcher instances with the `AbstractConfigAttributeRequestMatcherRegistry`

to the list of ignored `RequestMatcher` with [`WebSecurity#ignoring`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#ignoring--):

> Allows adding `RequestMatcher` instances that Spring Security should ignore.

in your [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure-org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity-) method:

> Override this method to configure `WebSecurity`. For example, if you wish to ignore certain requests.

For example:

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
       .ignoring()
           .requestMatchers(new MyInternalRequestMatcher());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below url intercept for the path which comes from application.

```
    <security:intercept-url pattern="path" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```